# String appending is acting really odd Python

Tags: python, string, append

Im trying to create a quick import script and i stubbled on something quite odd.

i do the following

```
print "insert into Log(ComponentId, Value, TimeStamp) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(8,{0},{1})".format(value, TimeStamp)
```

and i expect the result to be normal, tough the result looks like this

```
,15-08-2015 20:28:47)nentId, Value, TimeStamp) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(8,41,8
```

can anyone explain me why the Timestamp value is on the front and not the rear?

Comment: Can you show us your script? It could be that you are redirecting the output into a file, and something else is also writing into that file, or any similar case.

Comment: I am 100% sure `print(repr(Timestamp))` would give - `'8\r,15-08-2015 20:28:47'` . Can you check it out? If so, the `\r` is the issue, it moves the cursor back to start of line. Or `print(repr(value))` gives `'41,8\r'` .

Comment: Are there any control characters in the TimeStamp variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string value contains a `\r` carriage return character. This character instructs the print position to the start of the line. You can verify this by printing the output of the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr), which uses Python escape sequences for any character that is not a printable ASCII character.

Remove the character from the `TimeStamp` value; you could use `str.replace()` to do this, for example:

```
TimeStamp = TimeStamp.replace('\r', '')
```

Demo:

```
>>> value, TimeStamp = 41, '8\r,15-08-2015 20:28:47'
>>> print "insert into Log(ComponentId, Value, TimeStamp) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(8,{0},{1})".format(value, TimeStamp)
,15-08-2015 20:28:47)nentId, Value, TimeStamp) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(8,41,8
>>> TimeStamp = TimeStamp.replace('\r', '')
>>> print "insert into Log(ComponentId, Value, TimeStamp) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(8,{0},{1})".format(value, TimeStamp)
insert into Log(ComponentId, Value, TimeStamp) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(8,41,8,15-08-2015 20:28:47)
```

Note that your value still contains a comma! You may have made a mistake parsing this data from a file or other source somewhere earlier.

Also, using string formatting to interpolate data into a SQL statement is *not a good idea*. Use SQL parameters instead. Depending on your database adapter, that would mean you use `?` or `%s` as placeholders in the query, and the database adapter will then correctly *quote* the values to prevent SQL injection attacks and allow for optimisations in the query processing:

```
cursor.execute(
    "insert into Log(ComponentId, Value, TimeStamp) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(8,?,?)",
    (value, TimeStamp))
```

Refer to your database adapter documentation for details.